# Weak Convergence of Measures on $(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n}))$ using distribution functions.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request, weak-convergence

I am searching for a general proof for the following:

> On $(\mathbb{R}^{n},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, $\mu_{n}\longrightarrow\mu$ weakly if and only if $F_{n}(x_{1},\dots, x_{n})\longrightarrow F(x_{1},\dots, x_{n})$ at all continuity point of $F$, where $\mu_{n},\mu$ are measures and $F_{n},F$ are their induced distribution functions, respectively.

---

If $n=1$, then it is standard result for weak convergence. However, it is hard for me to prove this for higher $n$. The proof of the case of $n=1$ builds upon the fact that every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of open intervals, and there are only countably many discontinuity points of the distribution function. Then, we can rearrange those intervals so that the endpoints are not discontinuity points, and since everything is countable, we can still have a countable union of open intervals and the proof continues.

This technique does not work on higher $n$, even though any open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a countable union of open rectangles, because the distribution function now can have uncountably many discontinuity points.

I believe that this is a standard result with a tedious but smart construction, but I cannot find a reference for this. Is there any online notes or books I can go to for such a proof?

The books I have checked:

1. Probability,  A. N. Shiryaev
2. Theory of Probability and Random Processes, Y.G. Sinai and L.B. Koralov
3. Probability Theory, A. Klenke
4. Foundations of Modern Probability, O. Kallenberg
5. Online notes by Amir Dembo

(I do not read Durret).

Comment: See theorem 3.10.2 on page 198 of https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf.

Comment: I think you need to decouple the dimension of the sample space (presumably fixed) from the index used in your sequence of measures. You are currently using "$n$" for both. Use $n$ and $k$, perhaps.

Comment: @Kakashi thx mate!